# How to get the image resource URL in the src attribute of <noscript><img> tag when using next/image component

Tags: next.js, src, noscript, nextjs-image

I am using the next/image component and we know that next/image component injects a `<noscript>` tag with every image in my case the `<noscript>` tag has the same next/image URL like this in the src attribute:

```
src="/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fhome%2FDog-image-1.jpg&w=384&q=100"
```

which is a problem for crawlers like google bot as they get invalid_optimization_request and cannot access the direct unoptimized image resource with 200 ok status and thus wont index such images.

The way around this is to populate the src attribute in the `<noscript>` `<img>` tag like this:

```
src="/images/home/Dog-image-1.jpg"
```

This way the crawlers can locate the resource and index the images, it is a tested fact that google does crawl the `<noscript>` tag to index images and it ignores it for everything else.

Can anyone tell how to populate the resource URL in the  tag.

Thanks